# Foreign key one to one with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The `Customer` can have only one `Language`. I don't find the right way to create the key. When I get an object `Customer` the property `LanguageId` has a content but not the property `Language`. I use EF 6.1

This `Language` object will be use in other object.

I did this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LanguageMap());   
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.Code).IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Customer");
        this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
        this.Property(t => t.Code).HasColumnName("Code");
    }
}

public class Language
{
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class LanguageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Language>
{
    public LanguageMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.LanguageID);
        this.Property(t => t.Code).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Update (Language will be used in other object)

[image]

Comment: Can this code compile `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasRequired(a => a.Language).WithRequiredDependent.HasForeignKey(u => u.LanguageId);` ? I mean, can `WithRequiredDependent` be continued with `HasForeignKey` ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake this part of code was a test. I removed it.

Comment: I think what you want to achieve is one (Language) to many (Customer) and one (Language) to many (ProductDetail)

Comment: You are right of course. IT's very strange with EF

Comment: To have one to many, your code is already correct, you already mentioned with `[ForeignKey("LanguageId")]`, even without the foreign key attribute, the convention can discover the relationship, because it fits the [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: Sorry but no. When I get a customer, the property "LanguageId" is filled in but the property Language is null, should not be null. It's like this with NHibernate.

Comment: Perhaps what you need to have is adding `virtual` keyword on `public virtual Language Language {get;set;}` to do lazy loading or do the `.Include(x => x.Language)` to do the eager loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can achieve one to one with two options, but first you have to remove the foreign key value in the principal. Principal means that the record must exist first, that's why this entity doesn't need to have foreign key value, just foreign key reference.</s>

Remove this code.

```
public int LanguageId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
```

**First**. After removing above code add this configuration.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Language)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

**Second**, also add the foreign key reference on dependent (`Language`).

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Then mention the principal reference in `WithRequiredPrincipal`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Language)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Customer);
```

## update

To load language you can do it with lazy loading by adding virtual keyword (the context configuration must also enable lazy loading and proxy).

```
public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
```

Or do with eager loading.

```
var customerID = 5;
var customer = db.Set<Customer>().Include(c => c.Language)
   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == customerID);
```

Comment: Add a 'Customer' in 'Language' too ? I'll use this language table in 'Employee' and with more objects

Comment: Hmm then it's not one to one, because this `Language` can be owned by other entities, even without adding `Customer` property on `Language`, the code still one-to-one to `Customer`